# Is there a way to round the extremities of border-bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know if there is a way to make a border-bottom rounded.

Like this:

[image]

I understand that I could create an element, add a height, width, bg color and round it with border-radius, Actually, that is what I am doing in this image, this is a `span`. But I'd like to know if it is possible to make this with `border-bottom`.

I looked a lot, but I couldn't find an answer. In fact, I am almost sure that there is no way to do that, but if there is it would be great.

Comment: you can do it with before. with `border-bottom` only, best case you can do is half round by adding `border-radius` to your div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the use of `pseudo-element`.

[image: result]

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1>span {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h1>span::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 60%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h1> <span>Hello World</span> </h1>
```

Learn more about [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)